# PHP CodeSniffer: ERROR: The specified sniff code "Generic.Files.LineEndings.InvalidEOLChar" is invalid

Tags: phpcodesniffer, phpcs

My attempt to exclude the check for the EOL char on my Windows machine always results in this error message:

```
>vendor\bin\phpcs.bat --standard=PSR2 --exclude=Generic.Files.LineEndings.InvalidEOLChar src\version.php
ERROR: The specified sniff code "Generic.Files.LineEndings.InvalidEOLChar" is invalid

Run "phpcs --help" for usage information
```

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have installed PHP CodeSniffer via composer and am running version 3.4.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `--exclude` CLI argument accepts 3-part sniffs codes, but you've passed in a 4-part error code.

In your case, the sniff code is `Generic.Files.LineEndings` and that sniff only generates a single error code, so you'll be fine ignoring the entire sniff:

```
vendor\bin\phpcs.bat --standard=PSR2 --exclude=Generic.Files.LineEndings src\version.php
```

If you want to exclude individual error codes, or if you just want to lock down a standard for your project, you'll need to use a ruleset.xml file: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-Ruleset

Comment: Assuming a user doesn't just magically know the name of the sniff code, how does someone find a specific sniff code from a shown error/warning, in order to know which one to exclude?

Comment: Run PHPCS with the `-s` command line argument. The error message code will be displayed after each error message, and is in the format `Standard.Category.Sniff.Error`. If you want to exclude or change that single error message, use that 4-part code. If you want to exclude the while sniff, use the first 3 parts only.

Comment: @GregSherwood IMHO it's a shame that this rule (`--exclude` accepts 3-parts sniff codes) isn't documented explicitly anywhere...
Shouldn't this be added here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#limiting-results-to-specific-sniffs ?